# TVS diode with 10 - 15 V forward voltage

Tags: diodes, semiconductors, physics, tvs

I came across this TVS diode: https://m.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics/datasheets/tvs_diodes/littelfuse_tvs_diode_smf3_3_datasheet.pdf.pdf

It has a forward voltage drop of 10 to 15 V.
Why? How?
That is so unusually high. What kind of diode has that kind of a drop? Isn't it always roughly between 0.2 and 0.7 V?

Comment: An LED is a diode ….and it has a Vf much higher than 0.7V. It depends on the architecture and materials used. Some LEDs have a Vf that can exceed their Vreverse, such as this LumiLED: https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Lumex%20PDFs/SML-LXL8047MWC-TR3.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's often several volts because the forward voltage is measured at a very high current (for the size of the diode). It's a bit unusual for the forward voltage to be higher than the revese voltage, but it is possible for a small diode.

Here's a more detailed curve from a [larger TVS](https://www.littelfuse.com/products/tvs-diodes/surface-mount/~/media/electronics/datasheets/tvs_diodes/littelfuse_tvs_diode_smcj_datasheet.pdf.pdf) (from the same manufacturer):

[image]